# BeatifulSoup - Trying to get text inside span tags

Tags: html, text, beautifulsoup

I want to pull the text inside the span tags but when I try and use .text or get_text() I get errors (either after print spans or in the for loop). What am I missing? I have it set just now to just do this for the first div of class col, just to test if it is working, but I will want it to work for the 2nd aswell.

Thanks

My Code -

```
premier_soup1 = player_soup.find('div', {'class': 'row-table details -bp30'})
premier_soup_tr = premier_soup1.find_all('div', {'class': 'col'})
for x in premier_soup_tr[0]:
    spans = x.find('span')
    print (spans)
```

Output

```
-1
<span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span>
-1
<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span>
-1
<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span>
-1
>>>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="col">
 <p>Name: <strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span>    </strong></p>  
 <p>Date of birth:<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span></p>
 <p>Place of birth:<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span></p>               
  </div>      
 <div class="col">
<p>Club: <span itemprop="affiliation">Liverpool</span></p>
<p>Squad: 13</p><p>Position: Goal Keeper</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the text in the spans you can search specifically for the spans:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

If you want to find the spans with the specific divs, then you can do:

```
divs = soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'col'})
for div in divs:
    spans = div.find_all('span')
    for span in spans:
        print(span.text)
```

If you just want all of the values after the colons, you can search for the paragraph tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'col'})
for div in divs:
    ps = div.find_all('p')
    for p in ps:
        print(p.text.split(":")[1].strip())
```

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd suggestion seems to be giving me duplicated output. See below  Alisson Ramses Becker , 02/10/1992 ,  Brazil , Liverpool , Alisson Ramses Becker , 02/10/1992 ,  Brazil , Liverpool ,   . Also the 2nd div only has the first row as a span that I need then the 2nd and 3rd rows just contain p tags, where i need that data.

Comment: It sounds like you just want the values after the colons. If that's the case, you can just find the paragraph tags and then split the text on the colon. See my edit in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle's answer is good, but to avoid printing the same value multiple times like you said happened, you need to change up the logic a little bit. First you parse and add all matches you find to a list and THEN you loop through the list with all the matches and print them. 
Another thing that you may have to consider is this problem:

```
<div class=col>
  <div class=col>
    <span/>
  </div>
</div>
```

By using a list instead of printing right away, you can handle any matches that are identical to any existing records
in the above html example you can see how the span could be added twice with how you find matches in the answer suggested by Kyle. It's all about making sure you create a logic that will only find the matches you need. How you do it is often/always dependant on how the html is formatted, but its also important to be creative!
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me an example of how I would use the list right away? Ive got what I needed now. Basically got the spans from div1 + div 2 in one loop, then went to the next div and got the p, tags and stripped the text (with the help of kyles answer). When I do a find all and assign that to s string and check the type, it is of type <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>. For example  - spans = div.find_all('span') is span now a list or do I need to do something else to make it a proper list?